how to add volume controls to navbar in android 13 aosp
i am working on designing a custom android os build (lineageos 20 based) on a samsung s6lite LTE tablet as a car stereo replacement, but i am wondering if anyone is able to offer any changes i can make to the OS code to forcefully add a volume up and volume down button to the navbar at bottom of the screen so that its accessible from 99% of the apps which will be used on the device. the launcher i am planning to use (agama) has volume buttons already but i would prefer them on the navbar also
help:)
i have tried a number of custom navbar apps from play store but none work quite how i want and i ideally do not want to add more overlays than needed

create an app with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, which granted will allow you to draw above almost everything, seems perfect for described buttons case. simple app may take 100 lines of code or less
check out gif and tutorial in HERE

good idea that i will bear in mind but i would prefer something on the system level rather than forcing a overlay on top as tablet already has a number of apps that will overlay items (360 cameras, nav etc) and since im building lineage from source i am hoping someone can point me in the correct direction as to what code to change to add them
